# add unique images to spinner rows in android

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

I have managed to code to have images in each row of spinner but the images are all the same.I want to change each image. how do you do that. here is my xml and the code

xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 android:layout_width="fill_parent"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:orientation="horizontal">
 <ImageView
 android:id="@+id/icon"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:src="@drawable/calendar"/>
 <TextView
 android:id="@+id/weekofday"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

here is java

```
ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, R.id.weekofday, list);
dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(R.layout.row);
spinner.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
```

it displays the same image because it is set in the row.xml file. how do I make it dynamic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you create Custom adapter and write the code accordingly. As far as I understand that , its showing same image because you have set it in row.xml. But how would adapter will know that the image should be changed on each row.

In Custom Adapter you can set the image as per the position (i.e. index) of Spinner Item

Comment: I dont know how to do a custom adapter

Comment: Refer this link : refer http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidListView/article.html#adapterown_custom. Here He is trying to write the custom adapter. You can use the same. Let me know if you need more help

Answer (score 0):

```
         public class SavedSearchAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

          private Context mContext;
          private ArrayList<SavedSearch> mData;

          private boolean isEditMode = false;

          public SavedSearchAdapter(Context context , ArrayList<SavedSearch> data){
      mContext = context;
      mData = data;
           }


      @Override
         public int getCount() {
        return mData.size();
       }

         @Override
          public Object getItem(int position) {
        return mData.get(position);
        }

       @Override
          public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
      }

       @Override
          public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

       View view;
       TextView tvTitle;
       ImageView ivDelete;

        if(convertView == null){
            view = View.inflate(mContext,          R.layout.screen_saved_search_item_row, null);
        }
         else{
        view = convertView;
         }




         tvTitle = (TextView)   view.findViewById(R.id.screen_saved_search_item_row_tv);
         tvTitle.setText(mData.get(position).name);

         ivDelete = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.screen_saved_search_item_row_iv_delete);

         view.setTag(mData.get(position));

          return view;
           }


           }
```